# Can I disable wrap by div behavior in CSS3. Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

now I have such code, use bootstrap 2

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">Some text 1</div>
    <div class="span4">Some text 2</div>
    <div class="span4">Some text 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">Some text 4</div>
    <div class="span4">Some text 5</div>
    <div class="span4">Some text 6</div>
</div>
```

Can I get 3 rows in 2 columns each without code change?

3 columns and 2 rows I use for desktop, and need 2 columns and 3 rows in mobile devices

---

I have found it
http://jsfiddle.net/gkZKq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
.row-fluid { display: inline-block; width: 50%; float: left; }
.row-fluid [class*="span"] { float: none; margin-left: 0; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thespacebean/mDVfd/

Comment: No, I can't change HTML, css only. This HTML using in desktop version.

Comment: Thank's man! It works! Does it really to make output by strings? text 1 | text2, text3 | text4, etc. I have sorted data and sorts broken. Now browser output html by columns